# How to group nodes that have common edges from given string of pairs?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of strings that represents the edges of a graph.

**For example:**

```
["6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"]
```

Now I want to create a graph for this so I can see how many nodes are connected and how many are not connected. I am not sure what approach to follow for this.

I have used a Map in my program but I am not able to group the nodes properly in my code:

```
public static void process(int n, List<String> input) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (String in : input) {
        String[] arr = in.split(" ");
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int a2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        int first = Math.min(a1, a2);
        int second = Math.max(a1, a2);

        if (map.size() == 0) {
            Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
            s.add(first);
            s.add(second);
            map.put(first, s);
            continue;
        }

        boolean found = false;
        for (int k : map.keySet()) {
            Set<Integer> set = map.get(k);

            if (set.contains(first)) {
                map.get(k).add(second);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            if (set.contains(second)) {
                map.get(k).add(first);
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
            s.add(first);
            s.add(second);
            map.put(first, s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Now with this program I am getting a map with below values:

```
{5=[16, 1, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15], 6=[6, 11], 12=[12, 14]}
```

The problem here is, I already have 11 for map key = 5. So node 6 should be added to the set for key = 5 itself. So the map should look like this:

```
{5=[16, 1, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 6], 12=[12, 14]}
```

How to do this, what approach I need to follow here? Here I used a map just for convenience because in a later step I wanted to count the size of each key means: 5 has 8 nodes, 12 has 2 nodes, etc. Nodes which are not having edges are 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 10.

Here keys `5` and `12` are not important for me, they can be anything. Also, the order of values is also not important for me they can be in any order.

**Edit:**

In the input: `["6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"]`

say `"6 11"`, both `6 and 11 are nodes` and the `"6 11" represents an edge between nodes`. Now I just want to group all connected nodes like `"6 11 9 15 13 16 1 5"` and another group `"12 14"`.

**Update:**

I tried implementing the Javascript solution given by grodzi in Java but it is giving the wrong output, I made a mistake while conversion which I am not able to understand:

```
public static int process(int n, List<String> input) {
    Map<String, Integer> strToGroupId = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> groupIdToGroup = new HashMap<>();
    for (String in : input) {
        String[] arr = in.split(" ");
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int a2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        link(arr[1], arr[1], strToGroupId, groupIdToGroup);
    }
    System.out.println(groupIdToGroup);//{16=[16], 5=[5], 9=[9], 11=[11], 14=[14], 15=[15]
    return 0;
}

static void link(String strA, String strB, Map<String, Integer> strToGroupId, Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> groupIdToGroup) {
    if (!strToGroupId.containsKey(strA)) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(strA);
        strToGroupId.put(strA, val);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(val);
        groupIdToGroup.put(val, set);
      }
    if (!strToGroupId.containsKey(strB)) {
        int val = Integer.parseInt(strB);
        strToGroupId.put(strB, val);
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(val);
        groupIdToGroup.put(val, set);
      }

      int gA = strToGroupId.get(strA);
      int gB = strToGroupId.get(strB);

      if (gA == gB) return;
      // need to merge
      Set<Integer> eaters = groupIdToGroup.get(gA);
      Set<Integer> eatens = groupIdToGroup.get(gB);
      for (int n : eatens) {
        eaters.add(n);
        strToGroupId.put(n+"", gA); // the eateN now links to gA instead of gB
      }
      groupIdToGroup.remove(gB); // gB does not exist anymore
}
```

**Update using DFS approach**

Now I am trying to follow the approach suggested by Abhinav Mathur. Here is my Java code, it is generating wrong results:

```
public static void process(int n, List<String> input) {
    List<Set<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Set<Integer>> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        graph.add(new HashSet<>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        output.add(new HashSet<>());
    }

    for (String in : input) {
        String[] arr = in.split(" ");
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int a2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        graph.get(a1-1).add(a2);
        graph.get(a2-1).add(a1);
    }
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        dfs(1, 1, visited, graph, output);
    }
    System.out.println(output); 
}

private static void dfs(int node, int source, boolean[] visited, List<Set<Integer>> graph,
        List<Set<Integer>> output) {
    if (!visited[node-1]) {
        visited[node-1] = true;
        output.get(source-1).add(node);
        for (int neighbour : graph.get(node-1)) {
            dfs(neighbour, source, visited, graph, output);
        }
    }

}
```

For input `"6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"`, this program returns:

```
[[16, 1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Why not give every node a key in the map

Comment: @mitchel Paulin, can you elaborate how it can solve this problem

Comment: @MitchelPaulin This _does_ give every node a key. I'm not sure why you said that.

Comment: Can I just ask you, by what criteria do you name `keys` in your map, is it the first number or is it any number from the graph?

Comment: I added an answer below, so as to search the nodes I used an adjacency list and then searched each node keeping track of visited ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to suggest another solution. The first observation we need to make, is that we don't really want to get a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>`. The key, 5 for example, is no different than any other node. The reason it is the key, is only because it is prior in the list. Therefore I am going to build:

```
Set<Set<Integer>> map
```

Where for every 2 sets in this set, they have empty intersection.

### The algorithm

1. For every edge:

   1. Extract 2 vertices.
   2. build set with this 2 nodes.
   3. Go over all existing sets:

      1. Aggregate all sets that has one of the two vertices into a new set.
      2. Remove all sets from previous step.
      3. Add the aggregated set.

### The implementation

```
public static void process(List<String> input) {
    Set<Set<Integer>> map = new HashSet<>();
    for (String in : input) {
        String[] arr = in.split(" ");
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        int a2 = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);

        Set<Integer> aggregatedSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Set<Integer>> setsToRemove = new HashSet<>();
        aggregatedSet.add(a1);
        aggregatedSet.add(a2);
        for (Iterator<Set<Integer>> it = map.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Set<Integer> currentNodes = it.next();
            if (currentNodes.contains(a1) || currentNodes.contains(a2)) {
                aggregatedSet.addAll(currentNodes);
                setsToRemove.add(currentNodes);
            }
        }

        map.removeAll(setsToRemove);
        map.add(aggregatedSet);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

The following:

```
List<String> edges = Arrays.asList("6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16");
process(edges);
```

Will output:

```
[[12, 14], [16, 1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15]]
```

And the following:

```
List<String> edges = Arrays.asList("40 22","60 6","22 39","43 40","22 55","48 57","42 41","22 57","6 42","33 74","70 46","4 11","6 28","22 79","61 34","77 40","4 8","72 26","62 50","72 51","1 79","34 29","77 41","2 48","43 2","62 45","43 17","19 33","76 4","35 54");
process(edges);
```

Will output:

```
[[1, 2, 6, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 77, 79, 48, 17, 22, 55, 57, 28, 60], [4, 8, 11, 76], [70, 46], [51, 72, 26], [35, 54], [34, 29, 61], [50, 45, 62], [33, 19, 74]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confused by your code. A reasonable graph representation is a map from node to set of adjacent nodes, i.e. those connected by a directed edge. If the graph is undirected, then there will be mirrored mappings: from A -> {..B..} and B -> {..A..} for each edge A, B.

To implement this you want something like:

```java
class GraphForFun {
 static void addDirectedEdge(Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph, int a, int b) {
    Set<Integer> adjacent = graph.get(a);
    if (adjacent == null) {
      adjacent = new HashSet<>();
      graph.put(a, adjacent);
    }
    adjacent.add(b);
  }

  static Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> getGraph(List<String> edges) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();
    for (String edge : edges) {
      String vertexNumbers[] = edge.split("\\s+");
      int a = Integer.parseInt(vertexNumbers[0]);
      int b = Integer.parseInt(vertexNumbers[1]);
      addDirectedEdge(graph, a, b);
      addDirectedEdge(graph, b, a); // Remove if graph is directed.
    }
    return graph;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] edges = {"6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"};
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph = getGraph(Arrays.asList(edges));
    System.out.println(graph);
  }
}
```

This prints

```
{16=[1, 15], 1=[16], 5=[9], 6=[11], 9=[5, 11, 15], 11=[6, 9], 12=[14], 13=[15], 14=[12], 15=[16, 9, 13]}
```

Comment: But in my task, I want the group of values like this : `{5=[16, 1, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 6], 12=[12, 14]}`. Here keys 5 and 12 can be anything, not important for me. Also, the order of values is not important for me.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if it is correct to say this is a graph-related problem

Comment: Well @learner then you should not title your post with "build a graph." You should explain the problem you actually want to solve. Most of computer science and programming is doing this correctly.

Comment: I have updated the title now to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've understood, you basically track the [islands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/islands-in-a-graph-using-bfs/) in your graph. Since I'm not fluent with Java, I'll write a simple algorithm to solve your purpose.

1. Create a `graph[]`, where each key maps to an adjacency list. For every `i j` in your input, append `j` to `graph[i]` and `i` to `graph[j]`.
2. Create a map `output`, which we will now fill.
3. Start a DFS from the first node (or any node that you prefer). The DFS function would be like

```
dfs (node, source):
    if not visited node:
        visited[node] = true
        append node to output[source]
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(neighbour, source)
```

4. Check if any node is unvisited. If you find such `node`, you just have to call `dfs (node, node)`.

This will give you the desired map of islands you need.

Comment: I tried to implement this in Java, I am not sure where I made mistake, I am not getting expected output.

Comment: What is the issue with the output?

Comment: I am not getting expected output

Comment: Okay, but what is incorrect? If you can, give an example so that I can correct it

Comment: for input `["6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"]` output should be `{5=[16, 1, 5, 9, 11, 13, 15, 6], 12=[12, 14]}`, but the program I creatred based on your suggestion prints `[[16, 1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]` I have explained everything in my post and its updated section.

Comment: @learner there has been some implementation error on your part then

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory))
(more specifically apparently only their size)

You may lookup for better algorithms.

Since learning let's rediscover some wheel:

- If there is an edge between two nodes, link them
- When linking two nodes, one is the eater and the other is the eaten:
  link every node of the eaten's links to the eater

e.g

```
a1    b1
|     |
a2    b2
|     |
A     B
```

- `a1,...a2`, are nodes linked to node `A`
- `b1,...b2`, are nodes linked to node `B`

when merging `A` and `B`, (e.g) say `A` is the eater, `B` the eaten
then link `b1, b2, B` to `A`

```
a1    
|     
a2 - b1 - b2 - b // notice B lowercase since belongs to "group" A
|     
A
```

Below a js implem (java would take me too much time). Hopefully it is close enough to pseudocode ?

```js
/*
  strToGroupId     groupIdToGroup 
  _____________________________________
  strA ------> gA -----> { strA }
  strB --v
  strC --+---> gB -----> { strB, strC }

*/
strToGroupId = new Map // str -> int
groupIdToGroup = new Map // int -> Set<str>
const link = ([strA, strB]) => {
  // assign a group if new node
  if (!strToGroupId.has(strA)) {
    strToGroupId.set(strA, strA),
    groupIdToGroup.set(strA, new Set([strA]))
  }
  if (!strToGroupId.has(strB)) {
    strToGroupId.set(strB, strB),
    groupIdToGroup.set(strB, new Set([strB]))
  }

  const gA = strToGroupId.get(strA)
  const gB = strToGroupId.get(strB)

  if (gA === gB) return
  // need to merge
  const eaters = groupIdToGroup.get(gA)
  const eatens = groupIdToGroup.get(gB)
  for (const n of eatens) {
    eaters.add(n)
    strToGroupId.set(n, gA) // the eateN now links to gA instead of gB
  }
  groupIdToGroup.delete(gB) // gB does not exist anymore
}
const data = ["6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16"]
data.map(x => x.split(' ')).forEach(link)
console.log([...groupIdToGroup.values()].map(aSet => [...aSet]))
```

Comment: Can you please check my updated section, I tried implementing this JS code in Java but I made some mistake which  I am not able to find it. Can you see and suggest where I am making mistake in my code.

Comment: @learner I think it is part of learning to debug your code. Probably you should (as an exercise) really try to put a lot of println and check at every step if the junk output corresponds to your expectation. However my hint would be that since we missed nodes in output (like node 6) then 6 was eaten but addition to eaters has not been taken into account. Maybe in java getting a set as value from a map gets a copy (I don't know). In any case I would ensure that ```after``` the eatens are added, that getting ```groupIdToGroup.get(gA)``` does get me the eatens

Comment: @learner In your code, btw, you are calling link with ```arr[1], arr[1]```. Should be ```arr[0], arr[1]``` otherwise ```strA===strB``` all the time and you will never merge

Comment: Got it, I missed passing arr[0], also can you please help me in understanding what is the time complexity of your answer.

Comment: I'd say O(n^2) worst case (given input '2 1', '3 1', '4 1', '5 1'... we will copy i eatens at step i(and sum i for i =1 to n gives ~n^2). If we were to check who should be the eater and who the eaten, then I am curious about the answer I would hint O(nlog(n)) but not sure

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. My take on this was to build an adjacency list (map of the node ids and their immediate children) then search that to find the common paths.
A map `visitedAndGroupId` (ugly name!) is used to both keep track of visited nodes and which group they belong to. The key is the original node and the value is a group id.  Finally we iterate over the visited map and build out the groups and their contents so as to prepare the output.

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>> adjacencyList;
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> visitedAndGroupId = new HashMap<>();
    private static int groupId = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> pairs = Arrays.asList("6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16");
        adjacencyList = buildAdjacencyList(pairs);

        // find the groups
        // visit each node then its children then their children etc,
        // populate map of visited ids along with group id.
        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Set<Integer>> entry: adjacencyList.entrySet()){
            if(!visitedAndGroupId.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
                search(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                groupId++;
            }
        }

        // build groups container
        final List<Group> groups = new ArrayList<>(groupId-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < groupId; i++) {
            groups.add(new Group(i));
        }

        // populate groups
        // each key is our original id and the associated value is the group it belongs to
        visitedAndGroupId.forEach((id,groupId)->groups.get(groupId).addItem(id));

        // print output
        System.out.print("{ ");
        groups.forEach(System.out::print);
        System.out.print("} ");
    }

    private static void search(int parent, Set<Integer> children) {
        if(!visitedAndGroupId.containsKey(parent)){
            visitedAndGroupId.put(parent, groupId);
            for (int c:children){
                search(c, adjacencyList.get(c));
            }
        }
    }
```

Building the adjacency list:

```
private static HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>> buildAdjacencyList(List<String> vertexPairs) {

        // build adjacency list
        HashMap<Integer,Set<Integer>> adjacencyList = new HashMap<>();
        int group = -1;
        for(String s:vertexPairs){
            String[] pair = s.split(" ");
            int v1 = Integer.parseInt(pair[0]);
            int v2 = Integer.parseInt(pair[1]);

            if(!adjacencyList.containsKey(v1) && !adjacencyList.containsKey(v2)){
                // new pair
                adjacencyList.put(v1, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(v2)));
                adjacencyList.put(v2, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(v1)));
                continue;
            } else if (!adjacencyList.containsKey(v1) && adjacencyList.containsKey(v2)){
                // one vertex is new, one vertex exists
                addAndUpdate(v1,v2,adjacencyList);
                continue;
            } else if (adjacencyList.containsKey(v1) && !adjacencyList.containsKey(v2)){
                // one vertex is new, one vertex exists
                addAndUpdate(v2,v1,adjacencyList);
                continue;
            } else {
                // vertices already in hashset but this is a new edge between the two
                adjacencyList.get(v1).add(v2);
                adjacencyList.get(v2).add(v1);
            }
        }

        return adjacencyList;
    }

    private static void addAndUpdate(int newV, int existingV, HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>> adjacencyList) {
        Set<Integer> t = adjacencyList.get(existingV);
        Set<Integer> newSet = new HashSet<>();
        newSet.add(existingV);
        adjacencyList.put(newV,newSet);
        t.add(newV);
    }
```

Here is the Group class: (getters/setters not used for brevity)

```
private static class Group {
        public int GroupId;
        public int Count=0;
        public List<Integer> Contents;

        public Group(int groupId) {
            GroupId = groupId;
            Contents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void addItem(int n){
            Count++;
            Contents.add(n);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return  " " + Count +
                    "=" + Contents+", ";
        }
    }
```

The output is:
for input ("6 11", "9 5", "11 9", "15 9", "13 15", "12 14", "15 16", "1 16") is

```
{  8=[16, 1, 5, 6, 9, 11, 13, 15],  2=[12, 14], }
```

and
for input ("40 22","60 6","22 39","43 40","22 55","48 57","42 41","22 57","6 42","33 74","70 46","4 11","6 28","22 79","61 34","77 40","4 8","72 26","62 50","72 51","1 79","34 29","77 41","2 48","43 2","62 45","43 17","19 33","76 4","35 54") is

```
{  17=[1, 2, 6, 77, 79, 17, 22, 28, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 48, 55, 57, 60],  4=[4, 8, 11, 76],  2=[70, 46],  3=[72, 26, 51],  3=[74, 19, 33],  3=[29, 34, 61],  2=[35, 54],  3=[45, 50, 62], }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a couple of observations.

- The order of the data appears to be important. If you move `[6,11]` right after `[11,9]` it works as you expect.  In fact, I changed your input array to a `List` so I could shuffle it.  Each time your output is substantially different than the previous iteration.  This may offer a hint as to where the problem lies.
- I recommend you liberally sprinkle some print statements at key locations to do `state` checks as path to understand what it is doing.
- This has nothing to do with your problem but here is a sample of your code.  You already have set so no need to get it again to add the value.  Just use the `set` you already have.

```
Set<Integer> set = map.get(k);
 
if (set.contains(first)) {
        map.get(k).add(second);
        found = true;
        break;
}
```

It would also help others help you if you would do some explaining of how you expect this to work. Not everyone is fluent in graph theory.

Comment: 1) I'm getting input in random order so I cannot depend on the order of input values. The issue is with the order of elements itself as you mentioned. 3) I am already following the approach as you have mentioned adding the element to set.

Comment: Ok. But as I said, if you provide some detail about what the data represents and what you are a looking for (not the output but what the output means) we would be in a better position to assist.

Comment: I have added some details under the edit section in my post, please see if that helps. I am not sure if we can call this a graph or not.